# ConTeXt: How to setuphead with a definefont and font size relative to body font

Tags: context

I am trying to replicate a Word template that is made ... ahem "beautiful" ... by using a scattering of different fonts all over the place.

The body font is different from the heading fonts.

I have:

```
\definefont [sectionFont] [name:freakyfontname]
```

and

```
\setuphead [section] [style=\sectionFont]
```

which works except that I would like to add a size to the `setuphead` `style` that is relative to the body font size.

I cannot use `\tfa` and friends because then the typeface in `section` changes to use the body font (albeit scaled as I would like).

My (uneducated) guess is that I need to do something like:

```
\definefont [sectionFont] [name:freakyfontname at \some\maths\here]
```

but I don't know how to do this.

How can I `setuphead` with a `definefont` and font size relative to the body font?

Comment: `\definefont[sectionfont] [name:freakyfontname sa 2]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining fonts, you can use `sa` to specify relative font sizes. For example:

```
\definefont[sectionfont] [name:freakyfontname sa 2]
```

creates a font that is two times the default fontsize. Say, you want the section titles to be twice the bodyfont size, then you can use:

```
\definefont [sectionFont] [name:comicneueangularbold sa 2]
\setuphead[section][style=\sectionFont]
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\definefont [sectionFont] [name:comicneueangularbold sa 2]
\setuphead[section][style=\sectionFont]

\starttext
\startTEXpage[width=10cm, offset=1mm]
\section{Ward}
\input ward

\switchtobodyfont[14pt]
\section{Ward}
\input ward

\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Here is the relevant documentation from `font-ini.mkvi`

```
%D There are several ways to specify a font. Three of them are
%D pure \TeX\ ones, the fourth one is new:
%D
%D \starttyping
%D \font\name=cmr12
%D \font\name=cmr12 at 10pt
%D \font\name=cmr12 scaled 2
%D \font\name=cmr12 sa 1.440
%D \stoptyping
%D
%D The non||\TEX\ alternative \type{sa} stands for {\em scaled
%D at}. This means as much as: scale the bodyfontsize with this
%D factor. The scaled option is not that useful as one needs to
%D know the design size.
```

Comment: What does `sa` stand for?

Comment: @Manuel: See updated answer.